# KendoUI Data source Template CSS not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, datasource

I am working on a tree view in Kendo UI. I have a datasource and i am getting the data from it and binding it with an HTML template.

I am getting the output but the CSS is not rendered properly for a particular element. Please get the existing code in your local machine as `codepen` is unable to render the template.

```
[link]https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YMVGZL[/link]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "CSS is not rendered properly"?

Comment: Have you visited the [Telerik Demo/API?](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/templates)

Comment: Its Done guys :)
I had to give the css to kendos classes and it worked.